# How to get rid of row labels?

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, wxruby

What's the best way to get rid of row_labels? My program should work with CSV files, and I need only col_labels.

[image]

I'm going to make this column's width 0px. But is it the best possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the wxWidgets grid sample, specifically the Tabular Table Test, it hides the row labels with this code

```
void OnToggleShowRowLabels(wxCommandEvent&)
{
    m_grid->SetRowLabelSize(m_chkShowRowLabels->IsChecked()
                            ? wxGRID_AUTOSIZE
                            : 0);
}
```

So setting the column width to 0 seems to be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[HideRowLabels()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html#b81e66ed01683f271fd2fc73c8112156) method should do the thing. If you are using the latest SVN HEAD at least.